# PHP contact form returning zeros instead of information

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a problem with a contact form a created on a website:
The form only returns zeros where it should get the information entered by the user !
Before "echo" i tried $body_message and it gave me this : 
0
0

0
0
00
Now with echo i only get two zeros. Echo was sugested by a solution on another website where a user had the same problem but it didn't fix mine.
PHP:

```
  $field_name = $_POST['cd-name'];
  $field_company = $_POST['cd-company'];
 $field_email = $_POST['cd-email'];
 $field_budget = $_POST['cd-budget'];
 $field_info = $_POST['cd-textarea'];

 $mail_to = 'glxymedias@gmail.com';
 $subject = 'New project '.$field_name;


 echo "Name:  " . $field_name;
 echo "Company: " .$field_company;
 echo "Email:  " . $field_email;
 echo "Budget: " . $field_budget;
 echo "Message:  " . $field_info;

 $headers = 'From: '.$field-email."\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field-email."\r\n";

 $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

 if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to glxymedias@gmail.com');
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form class="cd-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
                <fieldset>                  
                    <center>


                        <p><label class="cd-label wow fadeInUp" for="cd-name">Name</label></p>
                        <p><input class="user wow bounceIn" type="text" name="cd-name" id="cd-name" required></p>



                        <p><label class="cd-label wow fadeInUp" for="cd-company">Company</label></p>
                        <p><input class="company wow bounceIn" type="text" name="cd-company" id="cd-company"></p>



                        <p><label class="cd-label wow fadeInUp" for="cd-email">Email</label></p>
                        <p><input class="email wow bounceIn" type="email" name="cd-email" id="cd-email" required></p>


                    <div>

                        <p><label class="wow fadeInUp">Budget</label></p>
                        <p class="cd-select ">
                            <select class="budget wow bounceIn">
                                <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="1">1000-3000R</option>
                                <option value="2">3000-5000R</option>
                                <option value="3">5000-10000R</option>
                                <option value="3">10000-20000R</option>
                                <option value="3">+20000R</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>

                    </div> 



                        <p><label class="cd-label wow fadeInUp" for="cd-textarea">Project Description</label></p>
                        <p><textarea class="message wow bounceIn" name="cd-textarea" id="cd-textarea" required></textarea></p>



                    <div>
                        <p> <center><input class="buttonsend"type="submit" value="Submit"></center></p>
                                </div>

                    </center>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

This is the new coe but it still doesn't work. I copied it from your answer. (opened with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
$field_name    = $_POST['cd-name'];
$field_company = $_POST['cd-company'];
$field_email   = $_POST['cd-email'];
$field_budget  = $_POST['cd-budget'];
$field_info    = $_POST['cd-textarea'];

$mail_to = 'glxymedias@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New project ' . $field_name;


$body_message = "Name:  " . $field_name . "\n";
$body_message .= "Company: " . $field_company . "\n";
$body_message .= "Email:  " . $field_email . "\n";
$body_message .= "Budget :" . $field_budget . "\n";
$body_message .= "Message:  " . $field_info . "\n";

$headers = 'From: ' . $field_email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $field_email . "\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) {
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
} else {
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to glxymedias@gmail.com');
window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: in your php script, do var_dump($_POST);

Comment: I added it at the start of the script like this : var_dump($_POST);

$field_name = $_POST['cd-name'];
$field_company = $_POST['cd-company'];
$field_email = $_POST['cd-email'];
$field_budget = $_POST['cd-budget'];
$field_info = $_POST['cd-textarea'];
 but it doesn't work still get two zeros

Comment: are you sure you are referencing the same contact.php script? please verify

Comment: **Undefined index: cd-budget in**

Comment: **Undefined variable: field in**

Comment: **Notice: Use of undefined constant email -**

Comment: **A non-numeric value encountered**

Comment: **Undefined variable: body_message**

Comment: enable error reporting so you can see your errors

Comment: the reason you are getting 0 on your message is because `$body_message` is undifined. m out you don't respond to comments, ping me when u available

Comment: Sorry I was out. Thank you for your time but I'm a noob on PHP so how do I enable error reporting ? How do I define $body-message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have said you are using `$body_message` without defining the variable first and you have couple of other errors.

Which are as follows:

`$field_budget = $_POST['cd-budget'];` **cd-budget** is undefined because none of your form fields have name attribute `cd-budget`  your `<select class="budget wow bounceIn">` is missing the name attribute therefore the value of it won't be pickedup by your script.

your select tag should be `<select class="budget wow bounceIn" name="cd-budget">`

`$headers = 'From: '.$field-email."\r\n";` this is wrong, you don't use `-` on variables you should use `_` instead, now this `$field-email.` reads as `$field` as a string which is also undefined, should throw a **Notice: Use of undefined constant email**

error reporting on top of your php script you add

> `ini_set('display_errors', 1);  error_reporting(E_ALL)`

This how your code should look :

your select tag on the html page should be this:

```
<select class="budget wow bounceIn" name="cd-budget">
    <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="1">1000-3000R</option>
    <option value="2">3000-5000R</option>
    <option value="3">5000-10000R</option>
    <option value="3">10000-20000R</option>
    <option value="3">+20000R</option>
</select>
```

then **contact.php**

```
<?php
    $field_name    = $_POST['cd-name'];
    $field_company = $_POST['cd-company'];
    $field_email   = $_POST['cd-email'];
    $field_budget  = $_POST['cd-budget'];
    $field_info    = $_POST['cd-textarea'];

    $mail_to = 'glxymedias@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'New project ' . $field_name;


    $body_message = "Name:  " . $field_name . "\n";
    $body_message .= "Company: " . $field_company . "\n";
    $body_message .= "Email:  " . $field_email . "\n";
    $body_message .= "Budget :" . $field_budget . "\n";
    $body_message .= "Message:  " . $field_info . "\n";

    $headers = 'From: ' . $field_email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $field_email . "\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) {
?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
} else {
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to glxymedias@gmail.com');
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Weird I got your two mails but they still have two zeros as a message. Also I tried it myself an got this : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$field_name' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/glxymedi/public_html/contact.php on line 3

Comment: that means u have a line above `field_name` that was not closed.. post your code

Comment: Aw yeah my bad I forgot to close the error reporting line. Now that I did that's what I get : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/glxymedi/public_html/contact.php on line 37

Comment: missing bracket maybe, can't know until I see your code

Comment: Yes better do that

Comment: @FrançoisMalet you forgot to close the else... The code I gave u above should work, use it as it is, was tested

Comment: Awesome dude! Thank you so much :)

Comment: One last question: I didn't understand how you defined $body_message

Comment: see what u did u used in your code u used `$body_message` inside the `mail()` function without first defining it and give it a value this is where I defined it `$body_message = "Name:  " . $field_name . "\n";
    $body_message .= "Company: " . $field_company . "\n";
    $body_message .= "Email:  " . $field_email . "\n";
    $body_message .= "Budget :" . $field_budget . "\n";
    $body_message .= "Message:  " . $field_info . "\n";`